# Can I copy the windows registry configuration from one user to another?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

My normal Windows 10 user account (non admin) has some issues with corrupted registry entries.

I have a couple of admin accounts where everything is fine and I would like to restore the values from one of those accounts into the registry entries of my normal user account.

Something like a copy/past between different branches of HK_USERS.

Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That heavily depends on which registry entries are involved. Some registry settings are dependent on others or on the presence of some software. Please give more information about these registry entries.

Comment: This is probably the best way to corrupt the registry! Have a look at [Microsoft registry checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-windows-registry-checker-tool-scanreg-exe-aaae4323-daa2-8477-5a4e-2a273779fdf0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export registry keys to a `.reg` file, and then import that into the other machine. Try to limit the scope of the export to specific keys, rather than the whole of HKCU or HKLM.

On the source/working machine, find the folder you want to export, then right-click it. Choose a location and save the `.reg` file.

[image]

On the target machine, click `File > Import` and navigate to your `.reg` file.